# Problem with render route component as function in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components, render, react-props

i have problem with function, which will render single Component with any params.

*My function looks like this:*

```
function renderProps(path, Component) {
    return (
            <Route path={`${path}`} render={(props) => (<Component {...props} isClickedHamburger={isClickedHamburger} handleClickHamburger={handleClickHamburger} />
        )} />
    );
}
```

I tried refer to this in ***Switch*** like that:

```
        <Switch>
            {() => renderProps("/home", Home)}
        </Switch>
```

*and i have error like that:*

index.js:1406 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Switch`, expected a ReactNode.

anybody know where is problem?

Comment: Try `{renderProps("/home", Home)}`

Comment: Why not render the `Route` directly? Try just `{renderProps("/home", Home)}`.

Comment: I dont want repeat these same code

Comment: {renderProps("/home", Home)} it works, thank you very much guys, greetings